# AWS athena SQL query on information_schema is failing

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, information-schema

I am trying to get metadata from AWS athena by running SQL query as:

```
SELECT table_catalog, table_schema, table_name FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'information_schema'
```

when I am getting an error:

> Database information_schema not found. Please check your query.

The query runs fine without the WHERE clause or some other condition there. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is there some reference you've found that suggests this should be possible, or that references `information_schema`?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: As I said, I am able to run the query without the WHERE clause. When I run it, for metadata I see table_schema as 'information_schema'. I am  not sure why its string value is confused to be a database in  the where condition...

Comment: Similar to: [Athena Presto list empty tables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49410867/174777) and [Apache superset: cannot read metadata from Athena](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48346345/174777)

Comment: This is an older question but I feel I should point out for anyone reading this later that the issue is that information_schema views contain metadata about tables and views, but do not contain any information about _themselves_, so `FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'information_schema'` is nonsensical.